# How to skip certain optional arguments in a library function

Tags: c#, function, arguments, twilio

I have been working on a Winforms C# application and I am using Twilio for SMS capabilities. Twilio has a function called 'ListSmsMessages' that looks like the following:

```
public virtual SmsMessageResult ListSmsMessages(
    string to, string from, DateTime? dateSent, int? pageNumber, int? count);
```

The Documentation says each one of these is optional. I can call the function successfully by either filling out no fields `client.ListSmsMessages();` or by filling out all fields `client.ListSMSMessages("to","from", date, 1,10);` but I cannot choose the parameters I want. Such as `client.ListSMSMessages("to",date);` only.

I have done some research and found that C# 4.0 should be able to do something like `client.ListSMSMessages(to:"to",datesent: date);` However this is not working.

I am wondering if perhaps because I am `using Twilio;` instead of writing my own class if that effects how I am supposed to call optional parameters? Or perhaps their documentation is incorrect in stating that they are optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are nullable parameters, not optional. If you want to skip some of them, pass `null` as value.

```
client.ListSMSMessages("to", null, date, null, null);
```

For more details:

- [Nullable types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).
- [Named and optional args in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

If you want optional args, then create your own function over the one in the lib (building on Robert's answer:) ):

```
public SmsMessageResult MyListSmsMessages(
    string to = null, string from = null, DateTime? dateSent = null, int? pageNumber = null, int? count = null)
{
  return client.ListSMSMessages(to, from, date, pageNumber, count); 
}
```

Comment: +1 I was so stick with `optional` parameters, that I had not even noticed they were nullable. Nice one! =)

Comment: Thanks so much! The reason I thought they were optional was because of the wording in the documentation. How did you know they were "nullable"?

Answer (score 4):

Building on Marcel's answer, here's what it would look like if Twilio really did built the function to have what C# calls optional parameters:

```
public virtual SmsMessageResult ListSmsMessages(
    string to = null, string from = null, DateTime? dateSent = null, 
    int? pageNumber = null, int? count = null);
```

Note how each param is given a default value that gets used when you choose not to pass anything in.

Comment: null is reasonable since this will be calling through to a webservice and the webservice will define the *actual* defaults

Answer (score 4):

Twilio has only two overloads:

```
SmsMessageResult ListSmsMessages()
SmsMessageResult ListSmsMessages
    (string to, string from, DateTime? dateSent, int? pageNumber, int? count)
```

You can either pass `null` to arguments you don't want or, if you want maximum readability, create your own extension method:

```
SmsMessageResult ListSmsMessages
    (this TwilioRestClient @this,
     string to = null, string from = null, DateTime? dateSent = null,
     int? pageNumber = null, int? count = null)
{
    @this.ListSmsMessages(to, from, dateSent, pageNumber, count);
}
```

With this extension method, you'll be able to call Twilio the way you want:

```
client.ListSMSMessages(to: "to", dateSent: date);
```

By the way, you can also create pull request for Twilio. It's on GitHub and they seem to accept them. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp

Comment: Minor point, but I would rename `@this` to `client`, mostly to avoid the escaped keyword.

Comment: @gunr2171 I prefer naming this-arguments in extension methods `this`. If the type is `TwilioRestClientExtensions` (that is, completely dedicated to extending one class), it feels natural.

Comment: Perfectly fine with that logic. Personal preference.